# how can i post a json string along with some parameters in windows universal application c#

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, dotnet-httpclient, windows-10-mobile

post a json value along with parameters in universal  windows application

example:

post 
http://sampleurl?param=1&param2=1
json body : [{"key":"value","key2":"value2"}]

Comment: What is the problem? Using HttpClient or building the URI or building the JSON?

Comment: Please upvote the answer so that others would prefer it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can create the parameters as dictionary and post it as formcontent

```
  public static async Task<string> postdataAsync(Uri posturl, Dictionary<string, string> pairs)
    {
        string response = "";
        try
        {
            var filter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
            filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Expired);
            filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
            filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(filter);
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent formContent = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpFormUrlEncodedContent(pairs);
            HttpResponseMessage httpresponse = await httpClient.PostAsync(posturl, formContent);
            response = await httpresponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;

        }
        return response;

    }
```